# regex to remove an entire sentence that includes full stops, commas and spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to remove an entire sentence. The phrase is:

```
www.mydomain.com is the best, in fact it is the best. So visit mydomain.com
```

I tried the following

```
\www\.mydomain\.com is the best\, in fact it is the best\. So visit mydomain\.com/
```

But it doesn't help.

Any advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a forward slash at the start, not back. `\w` matches whitespace, when I suspect you mean it to be the start delimiter.
Also, commas don't need to be escaped, so change `\,` to `,`.

With those changes, it works for me.

*edit*If you're just matching a phrase, you can use \Q...\E to avoid needing to escape all the special characters in it.*

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing / at the beginning and the end.

in vi the following worls fine:

s/www\.mydomain\.com is the best, in fact it is the best\. So visit mydomain\.com//

Answer (score 0):

As you don't say what language you're using, here is a perl way to do it:

```
my $str = q!www.mydomain.com is the best, in fact it is the best. So visit mydomain.com!;
$str =~ s/.*?\.( |$)//;
print $str;
```

**output:**

```
So visit mydomain.com
```

Php version:

```
$str = 'www.mydomain.com is the best, in fact it is the best. So visit mydomain.com';
$str = preg_replace('/.*?\.( |$)/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

This produces the same output.